# VBA Run time error on Worksheet_SelectionChange sub

Tags: vba, runtime-error, selection

I'm trying to figure out a way I can do a simple if statement to choose between two different statements in a Worksheet_SelectionChange Sub. If Intersect of one column is selected Then execute some code or if intersect of another column is selected then do some other code, if any other row is selected do nothing. Now unfortunately this isn't working as expected and drops a "Object variable or with block variable not set" error.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim CommentRow As Range
Dim TestRow As Range

Set TestRow = Intersect(Target, Range("J2:J10000"))
Set CommentRow = Intersect(Target, Range("G2:G10000"))

If ActiveCell = "" Then
  GoTo Cancel
ElseIf ActiveCell = TestRow Then
  GoTo TestRowComment
ElseIf ActiveCell = CommentRow Then
  GoTo CommentRowComment
End If
```

This should be quite simple but I'm really not sure why it drops an error before reaching the `Then` statement. It worked fine with just one intersect when I only had `CommentRow` as my single Range adding the second range I'm not able to workout how to make it work.

Comment: 1. Why `ActiveCell` and not `Target`? 2. Using `ActiveCell = ""` do you want checking the cell value? 3, Since `TestRow` is a range, what do you want checking when use `ElseIf ActiveCell = TestRow`? The cell value against the intersection value (problematic if more rows have been selected)? Or the to ranges? In such a case you should use `ElseIf ActiveCell Is TestRow ...`. The same for `ActiveCell = CommentRow`. I think it would be good to better describe **in words** what you try accomplishing...

Comment: 1. ActiveCell is because I want to determine what to do with the code depending on what cell is selected. 2. ```ActiveCell =""``` is there just to avoid running code when blank cells are selected. 3. I want to check whether the activecell is the same as the intersect value in the column, if any cell within either column is selected that has a value this should be yes.

Comment: 1. Always the selection will be `Target`. So it works the event... If you need the selection first cell (in case of more cells) this is another issue, but it also has to refer the `Target`. 2. Then `Target.Value` will better do the job...

Comment: Could you share the complete code since there are multiple issues with it? `ActiveCell` has no place in it. `Goto` is kind of reserved for error-handling and often leads to so-called spaghetti code. If you want to compare values, you e.g. need to use `TestRow.Value`. If you could also share more details, a screenshot of the worksheet and some sample data as text, surely someone could share an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the column without intersect:

````vb
Option Explicit

Private Const columnComment = 7  'G
Private Const columnTest = 10   'J


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c As Range: Set c = Target.Cells(1, 1)

If c.Row >= 2 Then
    Select Case c.Column
        Case columnTest     'column J
            'call sub for test
           
        Case columnComment
            'call sub for comment
            
    End Select
End If

End Sub
```
````

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't explain the Runtime error

Comment: I'm still not sure where my fault is for the original code but the above logic made me re-write my code to do the selection as above and then compare intersect values as I had wanted which works fine.

Comment: If you want to compare ranges you have to use `Is` - like FaneDuru explained